# Exit a Recursive Function in Elixir

Tags: elixir

I certainly have some catching up to do on understanding Recursion. I've got this

```
def query_url(id,page_number) do
 returned_response = HTTPoison.get! "https://some_web_page/#{id}/? pageNumber=#{page_number}"
  case returned_response.status_code do
    200 ->
      {:ok,returned_response.body}
    _ ->
      {:error,:not_found}
  end
end
```

... and

```
def recursive_function(id,page_number) do
   case query_url(id,page_number) do
     {:ok,response}  ->
        non_recusive_function(response)
        recursive_function(id,page_number + 1)
    {:error, :not_found} ->
        IO.puts "Exited"
   end
end
```

Assuming `recursive_function(1234,1)`, It was my thinking that the recursive function would exit once `query_url/2` returns `{:error, :not_found}`, but that's not the case, the recursive call does not exit.

All I'm trying to do is make a get request to a particular url, carry out  some actions as long as `200` status was returned and exit once a non `200` status is returned.

Comment: The code looks correct to me. Can you try `IO.inspect`ing every return value to make sure you do get the error case back?

Comment: @Dogbert, Issue was with the API provider, for whatever reason, they began returning 200 with an ERROR MESSAGE key where they hitherto returned 404. Thank you!

Comment: You might post the resolution you discovered in an answer and mark it as the answer so that others can see the question is now closed.

Comment: Highlights something useful to pay attention to, though... the base case should actually exit! (So you might want to put an upper limit on it or something)

Comment: Maybe you should answer your own question, I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Dogbert, Issue was with the API provider, for whatever reason, they began returning `200` with an `ERRORMESSAGE` key in an `ERRORARRAY` map where they hitherto returned `404`.

So replaced `case` with a `cond`

```
cond do
    returned_response.status_code == 200 and not returned_response["ERRORARRAY"] == []) ->
     {:ok,returned_response.body}
    returned_response.status_code == 400 -> 
     {:error,:not_found}

    true -> 
      {:error,:not_found}
end
```